# Technically, we can use matrices in non-orthonormal basis, right?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say there is a non-orthonormal basis formed by two vectors $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$. There's some linear transformation $A$ which gives $A|1\rangle=p|1\rangle+q|2\rangle$, and $A|2\rangle=r|1\rangle+s|2\rangle$.

Now couldn't we still express $A$ as a 2x2 matrix of $(p,q,r,s)$? And it's not just a notation thing. We could still do the matrix multiplication of the $A$ matrix and a vector $|v\rangle$ to get the correct answer. This is assuming $|v\rangle$ is also expressed as a column matrix in the same non-orthonormal basis.

One property that we lose is that the ith row jth column of $A$ is no longer the inner product $\langle i|A|j\rangle$. Is this why we only work with matrices in an orthonormal basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Once you fix a basis, you can always express a linear operator as a matrix relative to that basis. Orthonormality is not at all needed. It's just that sometimes, orthonormality may simplify the calculations for the matrix entries $a_{ij}$ (and sometimes it may not). In fact, many linear algebra books (eg Friedberg, or Axler, or Hoffman Kunze) do not even introduce the concept of inner products/orthogonality until much later on in the books (chapters 6,6,8 respectively).

In QM however (which I'm assuming where your qn comes about from), we usually want to work with an orthonormal basis (preferably eigenvectors of some operator of interest) because this will usually simplify other calculations one might be interested in.

Comment: In my understanding the orthogonality of basis in QM in more a natural thing then a matter of convenience. The state spaces can be seen as linear spans of the orthogonal vectors that corresponds to the results of measurements. So in a way there is no incentive for a general basis until specifically needed.